# Why isn't the destructor called for my dynamically-loaded Qt plugin class?

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, dll, destructor

In my C++ Qt application (a dictionary lookup/quiz program) I use plugins to provide functionality for all the possible lanugages somebody may want to add and use. These plugins are searched for and loaded at runtime from the main widget's constructor:

```
void MainForm::loadPlugins()
{
    QDir curDir;
    QStringList pluginFilter;
    pluginFilter << "*_plugin.dll";
    QStringList pluginFiles = curDir.entryList(pluginFilter, QDir::Files);

    for (int i = 0; i < pluginFiles.size(); ++i)
    {
        const QString &pluginFile = pluginFiles.at(i);
        QPluginLoader loader(pluginFile);
        DictionaryPlugin *plug = qobject_cast<DictionaryPlugin*>(loader.instance());
        if (plug)
        {
            plugins_.append(plug);
        }
    }
}
```

I used to think to think that I'm supposed to destroy the loaded plugins myself, so I iterated over `plugins_` (a QList of pointers) in `~MainForm()`, deleting them in sequence. Later I found out from the docs for `QPluginLoader` that I wasn't supposed to do that. Besides, it also caused a weird bug which caused the program to freeze when closed (but only after running under the debugger) so there was something obviously wrong with it.

I removed the delete section from `~MainForm()` and everything seems to work fine, except that I noticed that the plugins' destructors aren't getting called. I relied on those for saving some plugin-specific settings at application termination, otherwise I wouldn't have noticed. I put a breakpoint on one of the destructors and the debugger never entered it.

Here's the outline of the plugins:

```
// dict_plugin.h
class DictionaryPlugin
{
public:
    virtual ~DictionaryPlugin() {}

    virtual QString name() const = 0;
    virtual QString language() const = 0;
    /* ... */
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(DictionaryPlugin, "DictionaryPlugin")

// jp_plugin.h
class JpPlugin : public QObject, public DictionaryPlugin
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "JpPlugin")
    Q_INTERFACES(DictionaryPlugin)

public:
    JpPlugin();
    virtual ~JpPlugin();

    virtual QString name() const { return QString("Japanese plugin v1.0"); }
    virtual QString language() const { return QString("Japanese"); }
    /* ... */
};

// jp_plugin.cpp
JpPlugin::~JpPlugin()
{
    saveSettings();

    delete dictWidget_;
    delete settWidget_;

    delete kanjiDialog_;
    delete wordDialog_;
    delete radicalDialog_;
}
```

My question is, how are the plugins destroyed? Obviously they must be, when the OS reclaims the memory after my program terminates. How come the destructors are omitted? Is there some other way that I'm supposed to free them? Perhaps keep the original `QPluginLoader` objects alive in the `MainForm` class and then `unload()` them manually in the destructor? The destructors were also responsible for destroying some `QDialog`s and UI widgets the plugins own. Does this mean I have a leak when the program exits?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I tried storing pointers to the `QPluginLoader`s for each plugin. In `~MainForm()` I iterate over them, calling `unload()` and `delete`ing them. Works fine, except the freeze bug is back. When I close the application, the window disappears, but the program keeps running in the debugger. I can pause it but the stack shows just some unidentified entry points in ntdll.dll. Nothing immediately bad seems to happen, and it's not even visible when running normally, but somehow makes me uneasy.

**UPDATE2:** I left the program running in the freeze state (forgot to stop it) and found out it terminated normally after a while; it just took something like 20+ seconds. Now I'm absolutely amazed. What could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this on Google:

> QPluginLoader has its own ref counting and will delete the plugin when
>   unload() has been called for it for each QPluginLoader instance that
>   has a handle on it. unload() is not called automatically in the
>   QPluginLoader destructor so a plugin is never automatically deleted.

It dates back to 2010 but maybe you should try to keep references to your loaders and call unload manually on them at the end of the program.

Here is a link to the article:

[How to unload modules in Qt](http://steveire.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/the-mother-goose-plugin-loader-pattern/)

Comment: I did that just now, but the freeze bug returned. Updating Q.

Comment: Could the freeze bug possibly be due to something you are doing in your destructor (for example in saveSettings()) ?

Comment: I don't think so; I commented everything out of the destructor and it still freezes.

Comment: Seems freeze is no freeze at all, just a lag; see update 2. How it could be related to the plugins is beyond me.

Comment: Okay, it looks like this is something in my application that's not related to the plugin engine, perhaps memory corruption somewhere which interferes with the plugins' destruction. The Q was about the correct way to dispose of the plugins and you delivered so I'm accepting. Thanks.